# Wait for Observer to complete in Jest

Tags: javascript, rxjs, jestjs, observable

I'm quite new to Jest and RxJs and was asked to test an Observable.

```
const testComponents = ['test-component-1', 'test-component-2', 'test-component-3']
const nrOfComponents = testComponents.length

test('Activities get added to the taskStack', (done) => {
    launcher.observable$.subscribe((state) => {
        expect(state.taskStack).toHaveLength(nrOfComponents)
        done()
        }
    )

    testComponents.forEach((name) => {
        addActivityToTaskStack(name, 'standard')
    })
})
```

The expected behaviour is obviously for `state.taskStack` Array to have a length of three. However, the test already completes after the first item is added. How can I wait for the Observable to complete and only then run the assertion?

Comment: It's unclear how testComponents and observable are related. Is observable supposed to have a single value on completion? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that explains your case.

Answer (score 1):

The first `subscribe` callback runs on every value. The test should end on observable completion and also handle errors, which may be tedious:

```
let subscription = launcher.observable$.subscribe(
 function onValue(state) {
   try {
     expect(state.taskStack).toHaveLength(nrOfComponents)
   } catch (err) {
     subscription.unsubscribe();
     done.fail(err);
   }
 },
 function onError(err) {
   subscription.unsubscribe();
   done.fail(err);
 },
 function onComplete() {
   done();
 }
)
```

In case an observable is expected to receive one value and then completed, a straightforward way is to switch to promises because they conform to the semantics of described observable and are inherently supported by Jest.

```
test('Activities get added to the taskStack', async () => {
    const state = await launcher.observable$.toPromise();
    expect(state.taskStack).toHaveLength(nrOfComponents)
})
```

In case there are multiple values, they can be collected before `toPromise` for assertion, e.g. with `toArray` operator.

Notice that `toPromise` was deprecated in favour of `lastValueFrom` in RxJS 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can only take the number of streams and call `done()` when the observable is completed:

```js
launcher.observable$
  .pipe(
    take(3) // <- number of items to be added. It will be completed after 3 items
  )
  .subscribe(
    state => {
      expect(state.taskStack).toHaveLength(testComponents.length);
    },
    () => {},
    () => {
      done();
    }
  );
```

Not sure how the `observable` is triggered but you might need to update the `expect` expression.

However the above code will make sure that the test is completed after `3` items are added.